# Curl и сессионные куки

Tags: php, curl

Надо авторизоваться на сайте и спарсить некоторый контент через `curl`.
Как заставить `curl` автоматически сохранять куки и отправлять при следующем запросе без закрытия?

`COOKIE_JAR` сохраняет после `curl_close`. Открывать и закрывать для каждого запроса как-то неправильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не устраивает закрытие `curl_close`, то можно парсить заголовки set-cookie от сервера и в последующем добавлять при следующем запросе.

Но всё же, закрытие curl — это правильно.

Когда-то давно находил на просторах phpclasses классы для эмуляции браузера. Может поискать использовать их?